# System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message?

Tags: c#, wcf, microsoft-fakes

I'm new to MS Fakes in Visual Studio.

Can anybody help me out with an example on how to fake a `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message`?

I would like to control the return value of

```
message.Properties.Security.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

and

```
message.Properties.Security.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.IsAuthenticated
```

Is this at all possible with MS Fakes? I trued MOQ, but the `MessageProperties` class is sealed, so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Fakes does not support shimming of any types in the System.ServiceModel.Channels namespace. However, you can shim other types, like System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityMessageProperty, System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext and System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity. You may want to start by shimming the ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity property and return a stub of IIdentity.

Comment: How did you know that Fakes cannot shim that particular namespace?  I can't find any relevant documentation through Google.

Comment: When you generate the Fakes assembly, there are only Stubs in that namespace, no Shims. That's how he knows.

What that doesn't answer, and what you might have meant to ask, is "Why can't that namespace be shimmed?"